# URL for Facebook App

Tags: facebook, localhost

I don't have a website. So for trial purpose, I was using localhost(127.0.0.1) for my application. In facebook app settings, when I enter 127.0.0.1/myfblogin as URL, getting error as "is invalid because it is a Facebook url".

What is possible solution for this?

Comment: You're missing a `.`in `127.0.01/myfblogin`

Comment: Facebook maps `127.0.0.1` to the server executing the code, and yes, there's Facebook on the other side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for the question:
Replacing the localhost by any wildcard DNS.
I used 'fuf.me'.
So my final URL becomes 'http://fuf.me:8080/myfblogin'.

For reference, refer to below link for more wild card DNS.
http://www.fidian.com/programming/public-dns-pointing-to-localhost

These wildcard DNS redirect to localhost and are also accepted by facebook as app URL.

Answer (score 4):

facebook does accept localhost as an appdomain. Just try `http://localhost:8080/`

Answer (score 0):

Please try the private IP Address of your machine with http:// as URL in facebook app settings.

Comment: If I try "http://10.180.182.12:8080/myfblogin", I get the same error. 10.180.182.12 is my private IP address.